# Refining DFD of an RPG

Tags: game-development, data-flow-diagram

I am making a game to help childern learn Urdu (Urdu Boli = Urdu Language)

[image]

This is the high level context diagram of the game.Considering an RPG can any additions be made to the diagram?

Comment: googled this, now have new fave song

Comment: A player seems to be able to start the game and quit the game. Sounds more like video streaming if there is no player input in between those two.

Comment: This diagram is very simple. You could obviously add lots more to it

Comment: Are Urdu Boli and System (Game) two parts of the system which data flows between?

Comment: You probably should explain the design goals if you need feedback on the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What do you expect from the diagram ?

To be very provocative: What does your diagram tell you that you do not already know ?  Isn't this diagram confusing since Urdu Boli the game and everybody will wonder about its relation with the Game System ?

Also note that you foresee data to be saved, but at no place do you intend to reload this data.

### Users first ?

The goal of a [DFD context diagram](https://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/1433/What-is-a-Context-Diagram-and-what-are-the-benefits-of-creating-one.aspx) is to show how the system interacts with its environment at a very high level. But here it is misleading since Game system is not really exterior to your game.  And while I loved DFD for many years, I must say that nowadays it's somewhat obsolete.

I would therefore recommend to use-case diagram to show the sytems goals and to focus on the interactions with the users.  For this [UML use-case diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html) would be a better tool.

And if you're focused on users, a great way to go forward would be [use-case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook): these combine the advantage of the big picture and high level overview (that you expect from the context diagram) with user-stories to focus on implementable user experience.

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to clearly understand my diagram and its purpose.